# Comment traduire « responsible and accountable for » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, coordination

> The HIMS Manager is **responsible and accountable** for department
> operations, fiscal/financial management, quality, and service,
> environment of care/safety, risk management, and human resource
> management. [exemple provenant de [Mayo Clinic]](https://jobs.mayoclinic.org/job/rochester/manager-hims-cce-remote/33647/50974484272)

Comment traduire ce « responsible and accountable for » avec ces compléments ? Pourquoi pense-t-on employer ou non l'adjectif « [comptable](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/25202/le-vocabulaire/improprietes/imputable-impropriete-et-emplois-corrects) », se coordonnerait-il bien avec « responsable » et ces compléments ? Pense-t-on ou non qu'il créé un trompe-l’œil étrange quand on aborde la fiscalité et a-t-on d'autres suggestions ? Incidemment que pense-t-on de l'omission pure et simple de la traduction de « accountable » dans ce genre de contexte ?

Comment: to be responsible for=être responsable de, to be accountable for=être redevable accountabilité=redevabilité//https://commitments.fp2030.org/fr/etape6#:~:text=Qu'est%2Dce%20que%20la,des%20actions%20qu'ils%20entreprennent.

Comment: @Lambie Oui, mais que vas-tu faire avec la préposition _for_ et les compléments qui suivent si tu décides de présenter ces deux mots car il s'agit d'une phrase et est-ce idiomatique ? stp ajoute une réponse si tu veux explorer ça.

Comment: *How about you work out how to use the preposition and not ask me since I do not translate into written French*? I will not put in an answer because there is too much negativity à mon égard.  That said: Le notaire est responsable et redevable **de** ses actes. https://www.lanouvellerepublique.fr/france-monde/le-notaire-est-responsable-et-redevable-de-ses-actes for becomes de/des etc. in French.

Comment: @Lambie Since when does the person asking should work out the most intricate part of their questions while some random commenter provides some half-baked info about it and draws upon some arbitrary excuse to justify not contributing? I mean I don't need your help to figure out the meaning of those words, I can look up a dictionary. The example you provide is about professional conduct and the complement _actes_ is about him exclusively, whereas here we have notions pertaining to the business. That being said you should give answering another try, people are more receptive to answers imho.

Comment: A ce titre, **il est responsable *des* opérations financières** réalisées sur le plan comptable et pécuniaire. Sa responsabilité pénale peut être engagée. In this sense, he is responsible **for** financial transactions carried out in accounting and on a cash basis. https://www.francecompetences.fr/recherche/rncp/16867/ The point is that for becomes de/des d'' in French regardless of whether is it a notary, business, government or other for accountable, responsible for.

Comment: @Lambie _Responsable_ is used alone in these contexts, without _redevable_. Most likely for the reasons explained in the answer. Would you say _responsable et redevable des opérations financières_, that is the question.

Comment: Yes, I would **say that** as an interpreter, absolutely. Reasons explained in what answer? The single answer below is misguided as any *professional* translator will tell you. The notion of responsibility and accountability are not the same. https://hal.science/hal-01349991/document

Comment: @Lambie You are not the only professional translator around. That being said, the fact that these notions are different doesn't mean they can't be subsumed to a single word in the target language, as explained in the answer, again. Please read every single word of the questions and answers before commenting.

Comment: @Lambie I don't need help, I need answers, as does the community. Study-dropping is not help and the fact the word exists doesn't mean it's useful in the context of my question, I'm asking. If you don't agree with the answer, don't tell me, make a different answer.

Comment: The concept **in English** of accountability and responsibility are not the same thing. So, subsume *at your own risk*. I believe I am the only into-English (professional) translator here. Who else is there? I'd be glad to acknowledge him/her/them.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of your example:

- "responsible" indicates that the person has a leadership position,
- "accountable" that he may have to provide justifications and be liable for his actions.

In English :

- responsibility refers to someone's duty to carry out a task to completion,
- accountability generally refers to what happens after something has happened.
  [*source: The difference between responsibility vs accountability at work*](https://uk.indeed.com/career-advice/career-development/responsibility-vs-accountability)

En français, "responsabilité" couvre les 2 aspects (diriger et assumer).

Pour la traduction :

1. On peut omettre  "accountable", en particulier dans une fiche de poste pour un recrutement.
2. On peut dire que le manager est "en charge de ..., ce qui engage sa responsabilité" (mais, dans un contrat de travail par exemple, sans autre précision, ça ne voudra pas dire grand chose sur un plan légal).

Comment: C'est une bonne réponse, ça vaudrait mieux avec des sources pour toutes ces définitions.

Comment: accountable=rendre des comptes et être redevable de