# Comment traduire « labels and tags » ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, formulation-idiomatique

> Make sure you have all the labels and tags you need before proceeding with the
> sampling. [contexte médical]

Il s'agit d'un défi de traduction un peu similaire à ma question [précédente](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53305). On traduit généralement les deux mots par [*étiquette*](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/2082522/etiquette). Quelles sont des pistes de solution ?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147126/discussion-on-question-by-s-h-a-r-p-r-i-f-t-comment-traduire--labels-and-tags-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 3):

> Veillez à avoir avec vous toutes les étiquettes adhésives et volantes requises avant d'effectuer les prélèvements.

***Étiquettes adhésives*** et ***étiquettes autocollantes*** sont des dénominations courantes, c'est moins le cas d'***étiquette volante*** mais ce sera quand même certainement compris dans le contexte indiqué.

Dans le commerce, on trouve aussi ***étiquette à fil*** et ***étiquette américaine***.

[image]

Comment: Mon impression c'est que quand « labels and tags » est employé, ce sont généralement ces référents-là que le locuteur d'expression anglaise a en tête.

Answer (score 3):

Il y a une réponse dans les commentaires :

> Les étiquettes peuvent être autocollantes (labels) ou avec ficelle
> (tags). Donc, "all label and tags you need" peut se traduire par
> "toutes les étiquettes nécessaires". A part "vignette" (sticker or
> label), je ne vois pas d'autre synonyme possible dans ce contexte..

–
Graffito

Comment: Oui, je suis d'accord: autocollantes ou avec ficelle *ou bien* une fente dans la partie supérieure de l'étiquette par laquelle on passe le bout et qui la fait pendre à partir d'une barre en métal ou plastique sur une boîte ou autre conteneur médicale.

Comment: @Lambie Pourquoi pas ajouter avec une source ?  Tu peux contribuer à la réponse wiki ou moi je peux réviser, c'est comme tu veux.

Comment: Je ne trouve plus la source qui était un photo. Ta réponse est bonne.

Answer (score 2):

On n'a pas besoin de deux mots pour *labels and tags*, ce sont des [étiquettes](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%89tiquette).

> Soyez sûr de procurer toutes les étiquettes nécessaires avant de
> continuer.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147132/discussion-on-answer-by-livresque-comment-traduire--labels-and-tags-); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.